# How to find all tables/views used in a view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find all tables/views used in a view in MySQL?

All types of solutions appreciated. Either querying MySQL server with some query or parsing SQL code. Note that views can have joins.

For example, analyzing the following view:

```
SELECT
  `ColumnDefault`.`Id` AS `Id`,
  `ColumnDefault`.`ColumnId` AS `ColumnId`,
  `ColumnDefault`.`TargetName` AS `TargetName`,
  `ColumnDefault`.`Ord` AS `Ord`,
  `ColumnDefault`.`Width` AS `Width`,
  `ColumnDefault`.`Visible` AS `Visible`,
  `Column`.`ColumnName` AS `ColumnName`,
  `Column`.`FriendlyName` AS `FriendlyName`,
  `Column`.`Description` AS `Description`
FROM (`ColumnDefault`
  JOIN `Column`
    ON ((`ColumnDefault`.`ColumnId` = `Column`.`Id`)))
ORDER BY `ColumnDefault`.`Ord`
```

should return

```
ColumnDefault
Column
```

Comment: I need to show only tables, used by this given view.

Comment: And which tool are you planning to use for the extraction of the used tables?

Comment: I was thinking to draw dependencies with graphviz. Any tool is ok

Comment: Nice question... without solution I fear. A possibility would have been to extract the resuts of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM the_view` for further processing with a scripting langage, it would be easy because in the results there's column containing the table used for each step. The issue with this is that a long-time and never-fixed bug  in mysql makes EXPLAIN returning the tables' **alias** instead of real name which will totally break the idea if you used aliases in your views (most than probably). Still, give a check to that option. I really doubt you find something else.

Comment: I'm guessing now... Since you want a generic solution (as opposed to a specific, in which case you would know the table names and would not need a tool), I guess that you would need to teach your program to understand the syntax of the SELECT command. For instance, you could have `SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON..` or `SELECT * FROM A,B WHERE...`, and both phrasings are legal and, in this particular case, equivalent. You can even have a combination of the two methods. Moreover, you may have hierarchical selects... in summary, quite a mess, but doable.